# Shopify: alter price once certain quantity has been met

Tags: shopify

Considering Shopify for a new build but we have a requirement that the price of a products changes once a certain threshold of quantity added to cart has been met.

As an example.

Product A is $50 each.

If you buy 3 of the, it will be $150.

If however you purchase 4 *or more*... the price becomes $40 each.

Purchasing 4 will be $160, 5 - $200.. etc.

Am wondering what the options are for implementing such a system. All the ideas I can come up with has not been.. shall we say.. elegant.

Comment: how did you solve this issue?

Comment: @user427969 I ended up using a plugin called 'Quantity Breaks'

Answer (score 0):

You can create a product option that is priced according to your business logic, and then hide the associated variants on the front-end and rig the add to cart button to add the correct variant based on the quantity.